# Concatenating javascript files on the fly in Liferay

Tags: liferay, portal, liferay-6

I see a barebone.jsp file created (I guess by the MinifierFilter) as well as for deploying compressed and cached js. I want to separate development and production cases, and as for development, I just don't want Liferay not only to cache produced javascript file, I don't want to have this generated instance at all.

To be more precise, I want all javascript files to be concatenated on the fly. I always want to have an opportunity to edit **any** statics files at development and to see results as soon as possible.

What is the easiest way to implement it?

Comment: Sorry about that shabunc, I believe I miss understood your question.

Comment: Don't be sorry, it is almost always about bad questions, not bad answers ) Actually, I guess the most probable answer is - it is impossible or to pricey to overcome.

Answer (score 1):

include the settings from portal-developer.properties in your portal-ext.properties. This disables minifiers, caching etc. and you can develop without the problems mentioned. You don't want this setting in production though, as all files will be loaded individually.

(Edit: It might be advisable to include my comment from below in the answer):
You find this file in webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes

All the *.fast.load parameters are for the various minifiers (css, js), but typically you want all of the parameters named in there.

Comment: Olaf, I've mentioned I'm talking about development. Which property exactly cancels concatenation?

Comment: take a look at portal-developer.properties. AFAIK you want the "*.fast.load" values from there, but typically you just use all of them for development. You find this file at webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes (or google for alternatives how to include this file, but I like to copy the settings)